# insert data in HDFS using Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

let's assume that we have an external Hive table pointing on CSVs files on an hdfs directory.

so what happened when inserting a new line on this table using hive :

1. will the insert cause a whole rewrite of the table ?
2. or a a whole rewrite of the hdfs block where the data is located in ?
3. or will simply append the new line at the end of the file ?

Same question for the update operation

thanks in advance !

Comment: Forget about UPDATEs. There's a half-baked attempt at ACID transactions, but it requires ORC tables and a background compaction process.

Comment: AFAIK an `INSERT OVERWRITE` will nix all the files in directory then create 1..N new files (one per reducer if the `SELECT`requires a reducer step, one per mapper otherwise -- unless you tweak the "merge small files" parameters to reduce fragmentation). And an `INSERT` will just add 1..N new files.

Comment: Please note that HDFS files are **immutable**, there is no appending or rewriting *(OK, now you can do it but that's a deviant feature for queer edge cases; as far as Hive is concerned HDFS files are immutable)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question, thinking that you are using an insert statement and not using `INSERT OVERWRITE` with files.

1. No, insert will create a new file with the data you have inserted
2. No, only new file will be inserted
3. No appends are done to the existing files

Even if you use `INSERT INTO` and insert some files, then those new files will come and sit in the particular directory in HDFS without impacting existing files.

If you are using `INSERT OVERWRITE` all the files present in the directory of the given table will be deleted and new files will be placed in that directory.